# Npm install command error on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nodes, npm-install

C:\Project\Angular2Demo\Angular2Demo>npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Project\Angular2Demo\Angular2Demo\npm-debug.log

1. when i running NPM install command from project folder getting above error.
2. I already check my pc proxy deatils i dont have proxy I have direct connection through LAN.
3. i am windows 7 64 bit.

NEED HELP

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to update `npm` then use the following commands as per this [article](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade#usage)

Start Powershell as Adminstrator and run the following commands:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version latest
```

Comment: i got same error on powershell which i mentioned in question while running npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade

Comment: How did you install nodejs on your PC?

Comment: i used  this command to check proxy settings netsh winhttp show proxy got reply Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).

Comment: can you try to uninstall/install nodejs. It can be that npm is either not installed or is corrupted.